# Can't find mongoose module NodeJS require

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, restify

for some reason I can't get my require to work, it should just find both models fine but the path for the file just won't work.

- app

  - models

    - user.js
    - match.js
- server.js

Seems like a simple fix but cannot seem to do it myself right now. I'm using (var User = require('/app/models/user.js');)

Thanks guys.

Comment: where did u wrote require, which file

Comment: It's within my server.js

Comment: The exact error I am getting is Error: Cannot find module '/app/models/user.js'

Comment: try require('./app/models/user.js')

Comment: That worked, that is probably the last combination I tried haha, can you explain why that worked?

Comment: . Appended means the current directory path + app/models/.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you also can write it as,

`var User = require('./app/models/user')`

without even putting `.js` at the end, as it is added by default.. **Just a tip to know :)**

and here `./` means the current directory.

Hope it helps :)